# Nested object update

Tags: javascript, angular

I need to update abc object with key/value pair(checkboxSelected: false). This is dynamica generated array of object.

Actual Object:

```
[
 {
    "id": 1,
    "commId": 2,
    "recordId": null,
    "abc": {
        "countryCode": null,
        "name": "Not Available",
    }
 },
 {
    "id": 2,
    "commId": 3,
    "recordId": null,
    "abc": {
        "countryCode": null,
        "name": "Not Available",
    }
 }
]
```

Updated Object:

```
[
 {
    "id": 1,
    "commId": 2,
    "recordId": null,
    "abc": {
        "countryCode": null,
        "name": "Not Available",
        "checkboxSelected" : false
    }
 },
{
    "id": 2,
    "commId": 3,
    "recordId": null,
    "abc": {
        "countryCode": null,
        "name": "Not Available",
        "checkboxSelected" : false
    }
 }
]
```

I have tried to update above array of object using map method (Object.assign) but its not working.

Comment: @pilchard its not working for me. Actually its mapping array of object and in my case its only object.
```

Comment: Then show what you are trying and what isn't working, preferably as a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

You can use map() and spread operator as shown below:

```js
let arr = [{
    "id": 1,
    "commId": 2,
    "recordId": null,
    "abc": {
      "countryCode": null,
      "name": "Not Available",
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "commId": 3,
    "recordId": null,
    "abc": {
      "countryCode": null,
      "name": "Not Available",
    }
  }
];

arr = arr.map(obj => ({
  ...obj,
  abc: {
    ...obj.abc,
    checkboxSelected : false
  }
}))

console.log(arr)
```

Or if you want to ignore the use of spread operator, use object key like this:

```js
let arr = [{
    "id": 1,
    "commId": 2,
    "recordId": null,
    "abc": {
      "countryCode": null,
      "name": "Not Available",
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "commId": 3,
    "recordId": null,
    "abc": {
      "countryCode": null,
      "name": "Not Available",
    }
  }
];

arr = arr.map(obj => {
  obj["abc"]["checkboxSelected"] = false;
  return obj;
})

console.log(arr)
```

Hope it helps!